# Trying to Export Datatable to Excel (1.000.000 Records) in Web API and Angular, Writing Streaming is throwing an Out of Memory Exception

Tags: angularjs, csv, asp.net-web-api2, export-to-excel

Trying to Export Datatable to Excel (1.000.000 Records) in Web API and Angular, Writing Streaming is throwing an Out of Memory Exception.

Tried Splitting Datatables with 100.000 records each and writing stream seperately. However when I try to concat the stream, `Out Of Memory Exception` occurs.

Is it ever possible to export 1.000.000 records in an excel sheet. I am able to export upto 175.000 records. But require 1.000.000. See Snippet Below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadExcel([FromBody]AuditRequest auditRequest)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var response = GetAuditForDownload(auditRequest);
        MemoryStream streamFinal = new MemoryStream();
        List<AuditRequest> auditListForBulk = new List<AuditRequest>();
        foreach (AuditRequest req in response.Data)
        {
            req.FromDate = auditRequest.FromDate;
            req.ToDate = auditRequest.ToDate;
        }

        DataTable table = ConvertToDataTable(response.Data);          
        List<DataTable> splittedtables = table.AsEnumerable()
                                    .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
                                    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 100000)  //integer division, the fractional part is truncated
                                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
                                    .ToList();

        splittedtables.ForEach(delegate (DataTable SplitTable)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(ToCSV(SplitTable).ToString());
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.CopyTo(streamFinal);
            //byteArray = GetBytesFromDataSet(SplitTable);
            //byteArrayFinal = byteArrayFinal.Concat(byteArray).ToArray();
        });



        result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(streamFinal.ToArray()) };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "File.csv"
        };

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Consider that your audience do not necessarily know what a Lakh is...

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the thread doing the processing? Maybe the issue is that your available memory is insufficient...

Comment: Also - you write Excel, but the code says csv. there is a much greater overhead on an excel file. please update your question to clarify.

Comment: If you could share a sample row of data, we can calculate the required memory.